# Can I define a for..generate that doesn't generate anything for edge cases?

Tags: vhdl

Can I define a for..generate from 0 to -1 that just doesn't generate anything? BLOCK_WIDTH is a generic, which may be 0 for some edge cases (which is fine, we just don't need to generate anything).

```
Gen_Block: if BLOCK_WIDTH /= 0 generate -- Do I need this?
    Gen_Bits: for i in 0 to BLOCK_WIDTH - 1 generate
        -- Other stuff here.
    end generate;
end generate;
```

Comment: There are two nested generate statements, an if generate statement enclosing a for generate statement.  (It's not a for loop, note the lack of the reserved word loop).  What's the consequences of stripping out the enclosing if generate statement?  Does the design specification elaborate when BLOCK_WIDTH = 0? Does it run?

Comment: A range with a direction that doesn't match the bounds is a null range.  How many values in a null range? IEEE Std 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1. General, para 3:"A range specifies a subset of values of a scalar type. A range is said to be a null range if the specified subset is empty."

Comment: Using null ranges can be tricky ... for example Altera checks if all indices are in range so -1 can cause a bound exception before being evaluated to an empty range. Some operators are not capable of handling empty ranges ... but yes its possible to skip a loop/for..generate by choosing the right bounds :).

Comment: @user1155120, generate, not loop. My mistake. I asked the question because I can't get to a machine with a compiler on it, at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the enclosing if generate statement necessary?  No.

For a minimum complete and verifiable example:

```
entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
  constant BLOCK_WIDTH: natural := 0;

begin
  Gen_Bits: 
    for i in 0 to BLOCK_WIDTH - 1 generate
      -- Other stuff here.
    end generate;
end architecture;
```

This analyzes, elaborates and runs which tells us it syntactically and semantically legal VHDL.

For the case of BLOCK_WIDTH = 0 we see the parameter specification of the for generate statement condition would have the range 0 to BLOCKWIDTH - 1 (or 0 = 1 = -1).

IEEE Std 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1. General, para 3:

> A range specifies a subset of values of a scalar type. A range is said to be a null range if the specified subset is empty.

So how do we determine if the subset is empty?

11.8 Generate statements para 5:

> The discrete range in the generate parameter specification of a for generate statement shall be a static discrete range; similarly, each condition in an if generate statement shall be a static expression.

So what happens in a discrete range?

5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 para 2 (excerpted):

> ```
> discrete_range ::= *discrete_*subtype_indication | range
> ```

5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1 para 2 (excerpted):

> ```
> range ::= 
>     range_attribute_name
>   | simple_expression direction 
>
> simple_expression direction ::= to | downto
> ```

para 4:

> The range L **to** R is called an ascending range; if L > R, then the range is a null range. The range L **downto** R is called a descending range; if L < R, then the range is a null range. L is called the left bound of the range, ...

para 7:

> If a range constraint is used in a subtype indication, the type of the expressions (likewise, of the bounds of a range attribute) shall be the same as the base type of the type mark of the subtype indication. A range constraint is compatible with a subtype if each bound of the range belongs to the subtype or if the range constraint defines a null range. Otherwise, the range constraint is not compatible with the subtype.

(And each bound of the range for `i` is compatible with the base type of the range expression, which is integer).

So guess what? The VHDL code without the if generate statement enclosing the for generate statement is legal VHDL, there are no values of `i` in the subset of integer values that can cause elaboration of any enclosed concurrent statements or declarations.

So no, you don't need the enclosing if generate statement.

Comment: I don't know if I have ever seen such a complete answer for what was a simple question. Thanks! +1

Comment: There aren't many things that are simple in VHDL, some just appear so.